# remove flutter TextField Label Text background color

Tags: flutter, dart

**codes**

```
  Widget searchButton() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Arama",
        hintText: "Ara",
       
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow,backgroundColor: Colors.red),
        hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to completely remove the background color (red) in this picture (I don't mean transparent)

[image]

Comment: If you don't need that color then why are you setting that using `backgroundColor` property? Check the labelStyle and remove it

Comment: I think you just copy pasted this and so you dont know but you have:

`labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow,backgroundColor: Colors.red)`
just remove the 

`backgroundColor: Colors.red`

if you dont want the background color.

Answer (score 0):

you dont want the red color you can easily just delete it from the lable style ,
labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, backgroundColor: Colors.red),
just delete the **backgroundColor : Colors.red** in this line .

in my code i didn't have any trasprated box behind the Text and here is my code :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Widget searchButton() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Arama",
        hintText: "Ara",
        labelStyle:
            TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
        hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
      ),
    );



}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(child: searchButton()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When you remove it, a square-shaped automatic square (transparent) is created behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove **backgroundColor: Colors.red** from label style example code:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Arama",
        hintText: "Ara",
       
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
        hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
      ),
```

Comment: When you remove it, a square-shaped automatic square (transparent) is created behind the text.

Comment: can you please share screenshot.